# Model a blog with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

```
**db.province.insert({
    _id:1,
    name:"Kabul",
    zip:26000
});
db.province.insert({
    _id:2,
    name:"Herat",
    zip:27000
});
db.province.insert({
    _id:3,
    name:"Nangarhar",
    zip:28000
});**

----------------------
db.category.insert({
    _id:1,
    name:"political",
});
db.category.insert({
    _id:2,
    name:"Sport",
});

----------------------
db.person.insert({
_id:1,
name:{
    firstname:"shahid",
    lastname:"mamond"
},
address: {
**current_address:{
        province_id:1,
        district: "kabul city",
        village :"district 12"
    },
original_address :{
        province_id :2,
        district: "asmar",
        village :"asmar 2"
    }
},**
mobile:{
    home:"0778123472",
    work:"0747999307",
    personal:"076933307"
},
email:"shahid@mail.com",
password:"12345",
lastlogin:ISODate("2020-04-06"),
role:1
});

db.person.insert({
_id:1,
name:{
    firstname:"fazal",
    lastname:"mamond"
},
address: {
current_address:{
        province_id :3,
        district: "kabul city fazal",
        village :"district 12 fazal"
    },
original_address :{
        province_id :1,
        district: "asmar fazal",
        village :"asmar 2 fazal"
    }
},
mobile:{
    home:"0778123472",
    work:"0747999307",
    personal:"076933307"
},
email:"fazal@mail.com",
password:"12345",
lastlogin:ISODate("2020-04-06"),
role:1
});

---------------------------------
db.post.insert({
    _id:1,
    person_id:1,
    title:"first post",
    body:"post text here",
    category_id:1,
    published_at:ISODate("2020-04-06")
});

db.post.insert({
    _id:2,
    person_id:1,
    title:"second post",
    body:"post 2 text here",
    category_id:2,
    published_at:ISODate("2020-04-06")
});
----------------------------
db.post_comment.insert({
    post_id:1,
    commment:"post one comment here ! ",
    comment_at:ISODate("2020-04-06")
});
db.post_comment.insert({
    post_id:1,
    commment:"post one another comment here ! ",
    comment_at:"cur date"
});
db.post_comment.insert({
    post_id:2,
    commment:"post 2 comment here ! ",
    comment_at:ISODate("2020-04-06")
});
```

---

hi,

I am new with MongoDB, please review the above documents and need feedback just want to build a DB for a blog.

I want to normalize my documents using Document References.
What is the problem with multiple documents?

I have 34 province names that want to be used there id instead of redundant name.

- So can I join my documents for reading data?
- How to add PK an FK relationship at the code level?

Comment: You might want to start with a tutorial or explanation on MongoDB and NoSQL. The approach is very different if you are used to SQL.

Comment: Here is basic information about designing the data with MongoDB: [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/index.html). In general, the document data models are different from the SQL / relational data, though the concepts like relationships are same (1:1, 1:N and N:N). These relationships between entities are applied differently with the document data of MongoDB.  See this post: [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1).

Comment: no just what is the problem with above code ?